# NestJS UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.client.send is not a function

Tags: express, rabbitmq, nestjs

I'm building a nestJS api that uses express and tries to connect to rabbitMQ, evertyhing is at 99% I just have this final problem after all the necessary code was implemented

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { responseCodes } from 'src/common/helpers/responses/responses.helper';
import { towelModule} from './towel.module';
import { ClientsModule, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { RabbitMQModule } from './rabbit-mq.module';
import { Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
@Injectable()
export class towelService {
  constructor( @Inject('RabbitMQModule') private readonly client: ClientProxy,) {}

  async run(data: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const response = true;
      let pattern;
      

          this.client.send(pattern, data);
          data['users'] = 'new';
          resolve(data);
    
    });
  }
}
```

Why do I get (node:10816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.client.send is not a function
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10816) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

*EDIT!
I was able to stop the error like this

```
@Injectable()
export class towelService {
  constructor( @Inject('RabbitMQModule') private readonly client: ClientProxy,) {}

//async run(data: any): Promise<any> {
 //CHANGED TO Just 
run(data: any)  
   //DELETED tp  return new Promise(async //(resolve,reject) => {
      const response = true;
      let pattern;
      

          this.client.send(pattern, data);
          data['users'] = 'new';
         // DELETED  resolve(data);
    
    };
  }
}
```

but I never see anything in the rabbit queue. but the funciton is executing now

Comment: Can you show the setup of your `ClientsModule`? Have you tried adding an `onModuleInit` interface and method to run  `this.client.connect()`? Have you checked what `this.client` refers to?

Comment: Of course, I implement it here https://bitbucket.org/Harry_CCa/papertowel/src/towel/src/towel/towel.service.ts

Comment: And then I have a file for the Rabbit https://bitbucket.org/Harry_CCa/papertowel/src/towel/src/towel/rabbit-mq.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `@Inject('rabbit-mq-module')` instead of `@Inject('RabbitMqModule')` and your `RabbitMqModule` should have `exports: [ClientsModule]` instead of `exports: [RabbitMqModule]`. What's happening is Nest is seeing the injection token `RabbtMqModule` which matches the `RabbitMqModule` class's name, so the module class is being injected, not the client proxy.

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientsModule, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { TowelController } from './towel.controller';
import { TowelService } from './towel.service';
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'rabbit-mq-module',
        transport: Transport.RMQ,
        options: {
          urls: [
            'amqps://usermc:password@grouse.rmq.cloudamqp.com/xiuserc',
          ],
          queue: 'queue',
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
  exports: [ClientsModule],
})
export class RabbitMQModule {}
```

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
    ]),
    RabbitMqModule,
  ],
  controllers: [towelController],
  providers: [towelService],
  exports: [towelService],
})
export class towelModule {}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { responseCodes } from 'src/common/helpers/responses/responses.helper';
import { towelModule} from './towel.module';
import { ClientsModule, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { RabbitMQModule } from './rabbit-mq.module';
import { Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
@Injectable()
export class towelService {
  constructor( @Inject('rabbit-mq-module') private readonly client: ClientProxy,) {}

  async run(data: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const response = true;
      let pattern;
      

          this.client.send(pattern, data);
          data['users'] = 'new';
          resolve(data);
    
    });
  }
}
```